# How to remove win10 password/login screen on company laptop?

Tags: passwords

I have a work laptop.
There are many restrictions and one of them is to replace password evrey 3 month and using symbols, numbers, etc.
There is a way to remove the login screen?
(obviously netplwiz is blocked i'm not net admin)
Tnx.

Comment: No. That is dictated by policy from the company. It wouldn’t be very useful if you could bypass their security measures now would it?

Comment: of course you are right :) but it's very annoying and i just hoped thst someone have an easy way to do it.

Comment: This question itself is very likely a violation of IT policy at your place of employment, and would be very much grounds for dismissal. Please go to your local IT support people for any and all requests regarding your computer, and abide by their statements and rules.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question itself is very likely a violation of IT policy at OPs place of employment, and would be very much grounds for dismissal.

Comment: I would have to investigate this, but I seriously doubt, you can even set a default login to a domain user.  Even if you do, that doesn't get around the fact, you still have to change the password.  As an admin, if this type of violation happened, the user would be banned from the network.  If they could not get work done that would be their problem.  *That course of action wouldn't be up for discussion it would just happen.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about circumventing network security/policies at an institution.

Answer (score 1):

It is highly recommended that you do not do this. It will likely violate your company policy, and will probably get you fired.

If you don't have local admin rights and if the laptop is encrypted, the short answer is no.

Assuming your machine is not encrypted, and you can boot from a CD or USB, you can obtain access to an account with local admin rights by editing the SAM hive to enable, and blank out the password on the 'Administrator' account using the Offline NT Password Registry editor.

`https://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/`

Once you are local admin, you can run the command `control userpasswords2` as administrator to set a default username and password for login which will "remove" the initial login screen when the computer boots up. Note that this is HIGHLY insecure.

Comment: tnx. i do have local admin rights. also i don't have any speical info or data on my laptop. just alot of xls.